# foreach or ToArray inside a section, with js variable error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to do a `foreach` in a `section` in mvc 4. I just can't get it to get the scope of the js variable. So what happens here is that it wont recongnise the images inside the `foreach`. Ideas on how to solve it?

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = "";
        @foreach (var item in Model.Images)
        {
            //it does not know about the images varable here
            images += string.Format("[{0}/{1}],", "path", item);
        }
    </script>
}
```

I'm also trying this without success

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //statement is not terminated
        var images = @Model.Images.ToArray()
        console.log(images);
    </script>
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm just populating it with image names in my controller and passing to the view.

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public string[] Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: provide the model object structure

Comment: ToArray is camel case like toArray()

Comment: razor isn't camel cased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch back to HTML (JS in your case) with `@:` then back to razor again

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = "";
        @foreach (var item in Model.Images)
        {
            //it does not know about the images varable here
            @:images += "@string.Format("[{0}/{1}],", "path", item)";
        }
    </script>
}
```

Otherwise it assumes your `images` is a server-side C# variable, instead of client side content.

To answer your comment, you want to wind up with this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = "";
        images += "imagename1";
        images += "imagename2";
        images += "imagename3";
        images += "imagename4";
    </script>
```

So working backwards from that, here is the pseudo script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = "";
        // LOOP START HERE
        images += "@SERVER VALUE HERE";
        // LOOP END HERE
    </script>
```

If you have what looks like code inside a `@foreach{}` code block, it will assume it is server-side code.

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Images)
        {
            // This "must" be a local images variable as it is in a Razor code block!
            images += @string.Format("[{0}/{1}],", "path", item);  // Wrong!
        }
```

The `@:` escape sequence tells razor to treat the following as markup and not code. The `@(expression)` then injects a server side value into that client markup. The quotes are needed for the client markup constants.

### Slicker version:

```
  @section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = "@string.Join(",", Model.Images)";
        console.log(images);
    </script>
  }
```

Comment: could you just take a minute to explain why the `@:` and quotes around the string.format?

Comment: Yes I noticed that as I tried it. That was not the result I wanted. I just wanted to populate the string varaiable and then be able to use it further down. How can I achive that?

Comment: You are better off creating the concatenated string server-side and inject a single value. No need for all the `images +=` then.

Comment: Got ya. Yes as I notice that's the way to go actually. But just to know. It's possible right?

Comment: It does not want to accept the "char ," in the Join.

Comment: I get "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token illegal" with the last example. It's ok though I'll accept this answer but would be sweet to get that last part working though :)